# Get index of nested list item with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to get the index number of the list item that contains the anchor tag with the class selected in the active section

The LI i would like to retrieve:

```
<li>
            <a href="#" data-id="3" class="scene unchecked selected">The Health Care Delivery System</a>
        </li>
```

In this example I should get an index of 1

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="#" class="scene expanded checked">Introduction</a>
</li>
<li class="active-section">
    <a class="expanded">The Section 2</a>
    <ul style="display: block;">
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-id="2" class="scene checked">Introduction</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-id="3" class="scene unchecked selected">The Health Care Delivery System</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-id="4" class="scene unchecked">Determining Payments from External Customers</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-id="5" class="scene unchecked">Checkpoint</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="collapsed">Paying for Health Care</a>
    <ul class="collapsed" style="">
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-id="6" class="scene unchecked">Health Care Systems</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-id="7" class="scene unchecked">Find Savings with a Discount</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-id="8" class="scene unchecked">Checkpoint</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-id="9" class="scene unchecked">Defects in Ice Skate Pairs</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#" data-id="22" class="collapsed scene unchecked">Summary</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Here is what I tried, but it is not working

```
var innerIndex = $("li.active-section").index("li:has(a.selected)");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".active-section li:has(a.selected)").index();
```

You need to get the index of the correct `li` element.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/PKEBv/

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it

```
var innerIndex = $("li.active-section li > a.selected").parent().index();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/GZ9Hq/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking to use a [class selector?](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) that targets the link elements in the list?

```
var selectedElement = $(".scene").class("selected");
```

Although not a complete code answer (top of my head answer .. not even sure it works as is) it should get you at the same result in a simpler manner. You just have to make sure only one class has the 'selected' attribute but that is quite obvious and expected.

Happy coding!